# How to Create Multiple Drive Folder using Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

**Aim:** 
To create multiple folders (~100) using GAS.

**Problem 1:**
Using loops with `DriveApp.createFolder` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String)) does the job, but it take a long time to execute. I've done some measurement and it take about 0.8s to create 1 folder, that is 80s for 100 folders!
This is not practical.

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
  let folderID = DriveApp.createFolder('myfolder'+i.toString());
  Logger.log(folderID);
}
```

**Problem 2:**
Using [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) may be able to do the job, but I have no idea how to run `Drive.Files.insert()` in batch. I've only managed to create single folder thanks to [Tanaike's tutorial](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/03/30/how-to-use-fields-of-drive-apis/). Example code below

```
function CreateFolder() {
  let fileMetadata = {
    'title': 'myDriveService',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents': [{
      'id': '{parent_folder_ID}'
    }]
  };

  let respond = Drive.Files.insert(fileMetadata);
  Logger.log(respond);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create the multipe folders using Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the process cost for this.

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

In my answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use [the batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) for your situation. The batch request is run with the asynchronous process, and can run 100 requests by one API call. By this, it is considered that the process cost can be reduced. Here, in order to use the batch request with the simple script, a Google Apps Script library is used.

Library key:

`1HLv6tWz0oXFOJHerBTP8HsNmhpRqssijJatC92bv9Ym6HSN69_UuzcDk`

The folder is created with the method of files.create in Drive API v3.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

In order to use this sample script, please install a Google Apps Script library of [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest). You can see the method for installing the library at https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install.

#### 2. Run sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script. And [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  let batchReqs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    batchReqs.push({
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files",
      requestBody: {name: 'myfolder'+i.toString(), mimeType: MimeType.FOLDER}
    });
  }

  // Run batch requests using the library.
  const limit = 100;
  const split = Math.ceil(batchReqs.length / limit);
  let folderIds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    const res = BatchRequest.Do({batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: batchReqs.splice(0, limit)});
    const ids = res.getContentText().match(/{[\s\S]+?}/g).map(function(e) {return JSON.parse(e).id});
    folderIds = folderIds.concat(ids);
  }
  console.log(folderIds)
}
```

- When you run the function of `myFunction`, in this case, 10 folders are created in the root folder.
- In this sample script, even when `i < 10` of the for loop is more than 100, the script works by splitting every 100 request.

### Note:

- Please use this script with V8.

### References:

- [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

### Added:

When you want to create the folders in a specific folder, you can also use the following sample script. In the current stage, "EDo" method can be used. In this case, when the number of requests is more than 100, the requests can be processed in the library.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.

  const batchReqs = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => ({
    method: "POST",
    endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true",
    requestBody: { name: 'myfolder' + i.toString(), mimeType: MimeType.FOLDER, parents: [folderId] }
  }));
  const result = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: batchReqs });
  console.log(result);
}
```

Note: added `?supportsAllDrives=true` to the URL so it also supports shared drive.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks for this. Is there a way to modify the request in order to set parent folder ids? I've tried: `{name: 'myfolder #'+i.toString(), parents: [folderId], mimeType: MimeType.FOLDER}`, and got error: `SyntaxError: Expected ',' or ']' after array element in JSON at position 329`

Comment: @Max Makhrov About your question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike, that worked great with a usual Drive folder. When I used Shared Drive folder, I got error in the results: `File not found: FOLDER_ID.'`. I had permissions: "Content manager", which was enougth to call `DriveApp` methods. I'm sorry for commenting this, if you wish, I'll open another question

Comment: thanks for the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657423/5372400) and [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62461491/5372400) I've figured out how to solve this. Thank you very much again! I've added the solution to this answer. And I've also added library key to the answer, so there is a better chance it will be marked as correct.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you for replying and for your always support. Thank you, too!