# Create folders in a shared drive ( Google Drive API) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have a script that uploads a csv file to shared drive and it works fine, but when I try to create a folder it doesn't work. Not sure where I am going wrong
Code  that I am using to create a folder

```
    function createFolder() {
      var parents = '1XNBrOtnXJU1MhYv0nrAwTDXRZ'
      var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'sample_folder',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents' : [parents]
      };

  drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    fields: 'id'
  }, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
    }
  });
         
}`
```

[image]

Comment: Did you loaded the gapi library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the fetch API in your JavaScript. Just change the URL

**From:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true
```

**To:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true
```

---

change the mimeType in your metadata

**From:**

```
"mimeType": "text/csv",
```

**To:**

```
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
```

---

remove this line of code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('file', file);
```

and use the metadata directly as your request body.

Your code should look like this:

```
var parents = "18-7shshazxhkashjfk-xO";
var metadata = {
  "name": filename,
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
  "parents": [parents], // Google Drive folder id
};

var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify(metadata),
}).then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

### Reference:

- [Google Drive API Files:create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Thank you so much. I Tried the code it gives me a parse error .

Comment: @SarijaJanardh -  I added JSON.stringify to the response body metadata. Kindly try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: it works now .Thank you so much for your timely help .

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` MIME type and a title.

This link may help https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_folder

Comment: Hi Ashish .Thanks for the input. I did try changing the MIME Type but it doesn't seem to work with the drive.files.create. Is there a way using the fetch API .

Comment: @SarijaJanardh - Could you edit your post above and include the code you used in drive.files.create?

Comment: @NikkoJ. . I have edited my post with the drive.files.create